# Get the key value from multivalued array in php

Tags: php

I have an array

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [videoId] => FysV6XnDlQk [title] => Kannaana Kanney Song with Lyrics | Viswasam Songs | Ajith Kumar,Nayanthara | D.Imman|Siva|Sid Sriram [likeInfo] => Array ( [likes] => 1 [dislikes] => 0 [liked] => 1 [disliked] => 0 ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [videoId] => hXNSAb3s1XY [title] => Best of IRON MAN | Best of TONY STARK [2008-2018] [likeInfo] => Array ( [likes] => 0 [dislikes] => 0 [liked] => 0 [disliked] => 0 ) ) ) )
```

how can I get each videoId,title one by one

I have tried

```
$s=array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($myArray) ; $i++) { 
    $s[] = array($myArray[$i]);
    echo "<br/>";
}
print_r($s);
$ids=array();
foreach($s as $user) {
    $ids[] = $user['videoId'];
}
print_r($ids);
```

I'm expecting each videoId and title should be print one by one..I totally confused..If you give me small hint I'll work on that

Comment: What have you tried, and what is expected output ? try with any loop, ie. foreach or for .

Comment: @NikleshRaut I updated

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array_column to get particular key's value in multidimensional array

```
  <?php
  $data = array_column($yourArr, 0);
  $videoIdArr =  array_column($data, 'title', 'videoId');

  print_r($videoIdArr );

 ?>
```

Your output will be

```
Array
(
  [FysV6XnDlQk] => Kannaana Kanney Song with Lyrics | Viswasam Songs | Ajith Kumar,Nayanthara | D.Imman|Siva|Sid Sriram
  [hXNSAb3s1XY] => Best of IRON MAN | Best of TONY STARK
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this .You have two sub array inside the array .So you need to iterate via 2 forEach loop.

```
 forEach($myArray as $value){
    forEach($value as $subvalue){
     echo $subvalue['videoId'].':'.$subvalue['title'];
   }
 }
```